# How can i get all the images in this div to scale with the div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and have made a nav banner and split it into seperate images and housed them in the header. I need to scale the header and the content inside with the page and not have it squash below. Here is the HTML, CSS and javascript that i am using.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ySB9e/1/)

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/images/nav_over_01.gif','images/images/nav_over_02.gif','images/images/nav_over_03.gif','images/images/nav_over_04.gif','images/images/nav_over_05.gif','images/images/nav_over_06.gif','images/images/nav_over_07.jpg')">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><!-- end .header -->
            <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Blank','','images/images/nav_over_01.gif',1)"><img src="images/images/nav_01.gif" width="448" height="150" class="headerimage" id="Blank" /></a>
            <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','images/images/nav_over_02.gif',1)"><img src="images/images/nav_02.gif" width="140" height="150" class="headerimage" id="Home" /></a>
            <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Shop','','images/images/nav_over_03.gif',1)"><img src="images/images/nav_03.gif" width="120" height="150" class="headerimage" id="Shop" /></a>
            <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('blank','','images/images/nav_over_04.gif',1)"><img src="images/images/nav_04.gif" width="1" height="150" class="headerimage" id="blank" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="headerimage" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Gallery','','images/images/nav_over_05.gif',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/images/nav_05.gif" width="152" height="150" class="headerimage" id="Gallery" /></a>
            <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('About Us','','images/images/nav_over_06.gif',1)"><img src="images/images/nav_06.gif" width="196" height="150" class="headerimage" id="About Us" /></a>
            <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Contact','','images/images/nav_over_07.jpg',1)"><img src="images/images/nav_07.jpg" width="203" height="150" class="headerimage" id="Contact" />   </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Maincontent</h1>
            <!-- end .content --></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
            <!-- end .footer --></div>
        <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
  @charset "utf-8";
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #4E5869;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}


ul, ol, dl { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;  
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
a img { 
    border: none;
}


a:link {
    color:#414958;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
    color: #4E5869;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
    text-decoration: none;
}


.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 20;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: both;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
.headerimage {

    max-width: 100%;

    max-height: 100%;
}



.header {
    background-color: #6F7D94;
    text-align: justify;
    max-height: 10%;
    max-width: 100%;
}


.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
}


.content ul, .content ol { 
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px;
}


.footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #6F7D94;
}


.fltrt {  
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { 
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
```

Comment: Creating a fiddle will be much better

Comment: Fiddle? How would i do that? Im a novice at this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ you can post your code here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ySB9e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to set your header container to

```
display:block;
```

then set each anchor element within the header to have a certain percentage width. For the sake of argument, I've made them all equal and the sum of their widths is 100%. You can then set your images to

```
img {width:100%;}
```

in order to fill the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/ySB9e/6/

Just to mention: scaling images isn't necessarily the best practise; it'd be worth looking into setting breakpoints and loading a different background-image depending on the size of the screen.

You can read about media-queries over at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries